# GZipStream does not decompress data correctly

Tags: c#, gzip

I'm trying to compress data with GZipStream. The code is quite straightforward:

```
// Serialize
var ms = new MemoryStream();
ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(ms, result);
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

// Compress
var ms2 = new MemoryStream();
GZipStream zipStream = new GZipStream(ms2, CompressionMode.Compress);
ms.CopyTo(zipStream);
zipStream.Flush();

// Test
ms2.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
var ms3 = new MemoryStream();
var unzipStream = new GZipStream(ms2, CompressionMode.Decompress);
unzipStream.CopyTo(ms3);

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{ms.Length} =? {ms3.Length}");
```

Results should be equal, but I'm getting:

```
244480 =? 191481
```

Is the `GZipStream` unable to decompress stream compressed by itself? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

From the docs of [`GZipStream.Flush`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream.flush?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Compression_GZipStream_Flush):

> The current implementation of this method does not flush the internal buffer. The internal buffer is flushed when the object is disposed.

That fits in with not enough data being written to `ms2`. Try wrapping `zipStream` in a `using` block instead:

```
var ms2 = new MemoryStream();
using (GZipStream zipStream = new GZipStream(ms2, CompressionMode.Compress))
{
    ms.CopyTo(zipStream);
}
```

Comment: Interesting. It seems though that the async version `FlushAsync` does clear the buffers.

Comment: @Magnus really? GZipStream doesn't implement FlushAsync, which means we should fall back to Stream's implementation which just calls Flush in `Task.Run`

Comment: [FlushAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream.flushasync?view=netcore-3.0&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @Magnus Aha, "Applies to: .NET Core 3.0 Preview 7". I was looking at the Framework version. Looks like the [fixed `GZipStream.Flush` as well in .NET Core](https://source.dot.net/#System.IO.Compression/System/IO/Compression/DeflateZLib/DeflateStream.cs,171)